# Evaluating a string input to perform a function

Tags: python-3.x

I have made a conversion program where the user enters a number corresponding to the conversion. E.g. if the user enters 1 then the code performs the kilometres to miles conversion.

`if choice == 1:
    km = float(input("Enter the amount of kilometres: "))
    print(str(kmtomiles(km))+" miles")`

I want to make this so if the user enters `25cm to inches` then it will do the correct conversion

Comment: does the user enter the whole sentence, `25cm to inches`..?

Comment: Yes or any other conversion like 12 miles to kilometres @Ramesh-X

Comment: You can do this by splitting the input string. But if user misspell a word, your code will not work. So it is better if you can ask the user the type of conversion he wants at first, and then request to enter the values.

Comment: Yes I know but I have to do it this way too @Ramesh-X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input validation is a tricky thing since there are so many possible ways to break your code with bad input. Good code needs to consider all possible ways things can go wrong. For you specific use case when the desired input is "25cm to inches" or some variations of that you can use python [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) module and **named groups** to extract the relevant fields. An example is given below. You should probably put this in a try except block so that if no match is found then it prompts user again or breaks out of it. This is only a minimal example to build on. The dictionary `fields` contains the relevant information to use in another converter function.

```
#input.py
import re

pattern = "(?P<num>[0-9]+)\s*(?P<current_unit>\w+) to (?P<desired_unit>\w+)"

while True:
        try:
            convert_string = input("What to you want to convert? (press(q) to quit): ")
            if convert_string == 'q' or convert_string == 'Q':
                break
            m = re.search(pattern, convert_string)
            fields = m.groupdict()
        except AttributeError:
            print("Sorry, invalid input, please try again(or enter q to quit): ")
            continue
        if convert_string == 'q' or convert_string == 'Q':
            break
        if fields is None:
            continue
        else:
            print("You want %(num)s %(current_unit)s to be converted to %(desired_unit)s" % fields)
            break

$ python3.4 input.py 
What to you want to convert? (press(q) to quit): 25cm to inches
You want 25 cm to be converted to inches
$ python3.4 input.py 
What to you want to convert? (press(q) to quit): 340lb to kgs
You want 340 lb to be converted to kgs
$ python3.4 input.py 
What to you want to convert? (press(q) to quit): lb to kgs
Sorry, invalid input, please try again(or enter q to quit): 
What to you want to convert? (press(q) to quit): q
$ python3.4 input.py 
What to you want to convert? (press(q) to quit): lb to kgs
Sorry, invalid input, please try again(or enter q to quit): 
What to you want to convert? (press(q) to quit): 240 lb to kgs            
You want 240 lb to be converted to kgs
```

Comment: Could you explain the pattern string?

Comment: Any expression within parentheses represents the particular part of the matched string you want to capture, these are called groups. You can capture either by their position or you can name them as I have done here. A named group begins with ?P<name>.  "name" becomes key of the dictionary. [0-9]+ captures any number of digits and has to appear at least once (+) so it fails to match if there is no digit in the input. \s* matches zero or more whitespace and \w+ matches one or more words. You can also use \d+ for positive integers and \d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+ for floating point numbers.